# gcc configure --disable-shared fails to disable shared libraries during compilation, libgmp and libmpc conflict

Tags: make, gcc, rhel-5, shared-libraries

I'm compiling GCC on a build server to get access to the latest version of gfortran; after building gmp, mpfr, and mpc into specially-prefixed directories in usr/local, I configured and make'd gcc, which resulted in the following errors:

```
../../gcc/cp/g++spec.c: In function ‘void lang_specific_driver(cl_decoded_option**, unsigned int*, int*)’:
../../gcc/cp/g++spec.c:352: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgmp.so.3, needed by /usr/local/mpfr-3.1.2/lib/libmpfr.so, may conflict with libgmp.so.10
configure: error: in `/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Inside config.log is the following:

```
configure:3373: $? = 0
configure:3362: /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -v >&5
Reading specs from /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/specs
COLLECT_GCC=/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/usr/local/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/mpc-1.0.2
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)
configure:3373: $? = 0
configure:3362: /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3373: $? = 1
configure:3362: /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3373: $? = 1
configure:3389: /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:3392: $? = 1
configure:3580: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3602: /tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/./gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:3606: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3620: error: in `/tabletop/scratch/gcc-4.9.1/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure:3623: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The first log (the stderr output of make) seems to indicate there's a conflict between libgmp.so and libmpc.so, but the second (config.log from build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include) seems to show "-V" getting passed as a file and causing a missing input error. I've grepped recursively through the whole build directory and I haven't found anything that matches that broken option- can anyone shed some light on what might be the original cause(s) of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Building GCC sources was a pain in the a** but succeded in the end by folowing these simple steps :

after dowloading gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz and unzip/untar you should have a directory names gcc-5.2.0.

you must download few other packages like gmp mpc mpfr :

```
cd gcc-5.2.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

it will download and untar gmp mpc mpfr

It's hardly recommanded to do not build gcc from the sources directory so we begin :

```
mkdir gcc-build
cd gcc-build
.././configure (with your options)
make
make install
```

I suggest you start with a :

```
make distclean
```

in de gcc folder to delete everything was build before starting anything

Hope it helps and good luck